# gulp build/firebase deploy won't transfer images or videos

Tags: image, deployment, firebase, gulp, transfer

I am trying to deploy my application, which works fine locally. When I use gulp build it says I have all of the files I need. When I do firebase deploy it says that everything uploaded. However, when I use firebase open it makes
[it gives me the following 404 errors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGZak.png)

[Here is what comes up when I do gulp build and firebase deploy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7pRo.png)

I can send the gulp-babel.js file upon request. Thanks in advance for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, you are having a problem with your gulp-babel.js file. The gulp imagemin plugin is probably what you need.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-imagemin

Then somewhere in that file make sure you are creating something like this.

```
gulp.task('images', () => {
    return gulp.src('app/images/*')
        .pipe($.imagemin({
            progressive: true,
            svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'));
})
```

See this if you have gulp-load-plugins: [gulp-load-plugins not loading plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29288870/gulp-load-plugins-not-loading-plugins)

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed. I did the same for the videos. Worked like a charm!

Comment: Now I'm trying to add videos as well. I thought it was working but only one video showed up. Can you tell me what I need to do with the videos other than minify them? Do you have any links to the documentation other than just straight up going to gulpjs?